# How to copy the contents of many folders to one?

Tags: rhythmbox

I have several music files all in individual folders by artist name that I want to copy to one location so rhythmbox can import all the files from the single location. I've seen simple program solutions to this but none for Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi & welcome? Why you realy need from some to one copy? Simple copy files manualy.

Comment: He has the same case as me. I had too many folders with 1 or 2 mp3 files (About 40.000 mp3 files with 20.000 folders, each one containing between 0 mp3 files to 50 mp3 files. So after cleaning the folders from dupe and simply wanted all mp3 in the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

To move the files do this:

`find /my/files/path -iname "*.mp3" -exec mv {} /home/user/music \;`

It works like this, the first **/my/files/path** is where you want to look. The part that says **/home/user/music** is where you want to move all files to. So let us say you have all music inside your home folder in `/home/jon/music` and want to move it to `home/jon/newmusic` then do this:

`find /home/jon/music -iname "*.mp3" -exec mv {} /home/jon/newmusic \;`

If it is on the same drive the origin and destination then it will do it really fast. If it is in another hard drive like `/media/jon/backup/music` then it will depend on hard drive speed.

If you prefer to copy instead of move the files, you must use cp:

```
find /home/jon/music -iname "*.mp3" -exec cp {} /home/jon/newmusic \;
```

Comment: This is assuming all your music files are mp3s.

Comment: Would be easier to change to another format, simply replace the .mp3 there hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Took it from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1385966

DO NOT ACCIDENTALLY DO THIS IN YOUR HOME FOLDER.

Change to the top directory containing all these files and execute

`find ./ -type f -exec cp '{}' ./ \;`

According to the man page for find you might need to escape the {} too.

Answer (score 0):

Or if You prefer scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
# to get description use the -h flag

# ==========
# preambula:

PROGNAME=${0##*/}
PROGVERSION=1.0
Name="*"
destDir=`basename ${0##*/} .bash`

# colors:
BLUE='\033[94m'
GREEN="\e[0;32m"
RED='\033[91m'
BLACK='\033[0m'

usage()
{
cat << EO
Usage: $PROGNAME <folder>

Copies files matching rgxp (default to all files) from the current dir
and its child dirs to the specified dir (default to $destDir).

I recomment back-up files before running this script.

Options:
EO
cat <<EO | column -s\& -t

  -d, --dest & destination dir (default to $destDir)
  -n, --name & files-of-interest shell-style rgxp (default to $Name)
 
  -h, --help & show this output
  -v, --version & show version information
      --nocolors & disable colors in output. In case Your terminal doesn't support coloring and You get the output like \"\\033[94mthis\" or Your terminal colors \"conflict\" with the output coloring"
EO
}

SHORTOPTS="hvn:d:"
LONGOPTS="help,version,nocolors,name:dest:"

ARGS=$(getopt -s bash --options $SHORTOPTS --longoptions $LONGOPTS --name $PROGNAME -- "$@")

eval set -- "$ARGS"

while true; do
    case $1 in

        -n|--name)
            Name=$2; shift;;
        -d|--dest)
            destDir=$2; shift;;

        -h|--help)
            usage; exit 0;;
        -v|--version)
            echo "$PROGVERSION"; exit 0;;
        --nocolors)
            noColors=true;;
        --)
            shift; break;;
        *)
            shift; break;;
    esac
    shift
done


# ===================
# finally the script:

# making a dir:
if [ -d "$destDir" ]; then
    rm -rf "$destDir"
fi
mkdir "$destDir"

# copying!
numberOfFiles=0
find . -type f -name "$Name" | {
while read fl; do
    echo -e "${RED}${PROGNAME}: ${GREEN}Copying \"$fl\" ..\c${BLACK}"
    cp "$fl" "$destDir/`basename "$fl"`"
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo " OK"
        numberOfFiles=`expr $numberOfFiles + 1`
    fi
done
echo -e "${RED}${PROGNAME}: ${GREEN}$numberOfFiles files got copied to \"$destDir\"${BLACK}"
}


# ===========
## reporting:

echo -e "${RED}${PROGNAME}: ${GREEN}Done.${BLACK}"
```

Comment: Well somebody had to come and make the best answer possible. Have not test the script but if it does what I can read it will look pretty cool.

Comment: This is an [old](https://github.com/bk322/bk_automates/blob/master/bk_copies/bk_copies_them_all.bash) script and I don't use it any more. Here's more general [one](https://github.com/bk322/bk_automates/blob/master/bk_copies/bk_files_from_dirs.py).